# What is the location of user customisation settings TortoiseGIT on Windows 10?

Tags: tortoisegit

I would like to install TortoiseGIT on to a few devices but I would like to override the defaults in the context menu settings. I was assuming these settings would be in a config file the user profile or registry but I can't find them.

Does anyone know where the context menu customisations are stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've now found this and to posting here to save others time.

The settings appear to all be stored in the Registry rather than file configs. If you `look under Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseGit` you will find a number of ContextMenuEntries keys which I believe control the context menu settings.

Comment: Yes. See [TortoiseGit Daily Use Guide | TortoiseGit's Settings | Exporting TortoiseGit Settings](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-export).

Comment: Also see [my article](http://www.marcoeckstein.com/it/how-to-share-tortoisegit-settings-between-multiple-machines/).